# How is updatedb so much faster than find?

Tags: find, locate, updatedb

How is `updatedb` so much faster than `find`?

Here's a timed comparison between `updatedb` and a `find` command that does a seemingly similar task.

compare.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cmd="sudo updatedb"
echo $cmd
time eval $cmd

cmd="sudo find / \
    -fstype ext4 \
    -not \( \
        -path '/afs/*' -o \
        -path '/net/*' -o \
        -path '/sfs/*' -o \
        -path '/tmp/*' -o \
        -path '/udev/*' -o \
        -path '/var/cache/*' -o \
        -path '/var/lib/pacman/local/*' -o \
        -path '/var/lock/*' -o \
        -path '/var/run/*' -o \
        -path '/var/spool/*' -o \
        -path '/var/tmp/*' -o \
        -path '/proc/*' \
    \) &>/dev/null"

echo $cmd
time eval $cmd
```

My /etc/updatedb.conf:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS = "yes"
PRUNEFS = "9p afs anon_inodefs auto autofs bdev binfmt_misc cgroup cifs coda configfs cpuset cramfs debugfs devpts devtmpfs ecryptfs exofs ftpfs fuse fuse.encfs fuse.sshfs fusectl gfs gfs2 hugetlbfs inotifyfs iso9660 jffs2 lustre mqueue ncpfs nfs nfs4 nfsd pipefs proc ramfs rootfs rpc_pipefs securityfs selinuxfs sfs shfs smbfs sockfs sshfs sysfs tmpfs ubifs udf usbfs vboxsf"
PRUNENAMES = ".git .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS = "/afs /net /sfs /tmp /udev /var/cache /var/lib/pacman/local /var/lock /var/run /var/spool /var/tmp"
```

For the find command I just specified `ext4` filesystem because that's the only filesystem `updatedb` should end up looking through. I didn't bother with the file extensions and I don't know how to exclude a bind mount from `find` but I don't have any. I also added an exclusion for '/proc' which it seems that `updatedb` ignores. I should have also ignored '/sys'.

If there'd be any difference I'd expect the find command to be a little faster since it's rules are a little simpler and it doesn't have to write to disk. Instead `updatedb` is much faster.

```
$ ./compare.sh
sudo updatedb

real    0m0.876s
user    0m0.443s
sys 0m0.273s

sudo find / -fstype ext4 -not \( -path '/afs/*' -o -path '/net/*' -o -path '/sfs/*' -o -path '/tmp/*' -o -path '/udev/*' -o -path '/var/cache/*' -o -path '/var/lib/pacman/local/*' -o -path '/var/lock/*' -o -path '/var/run/*' -o -path '/var/spool/*' -o -path '/var/tmp/*' -o -path '/proc/*' \) &>/dev/null

real    6m23.499s
user    0m14.527s
sys 0m10.993s
```

What are they doing differently?

Comment: use `set -x` to turn on printing of commands before they're executed, so you don't need the eval shenanigans.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the man page for `updatedb`, "If the database already exists, its data is reused to avoid rereading directories that have not changed".

Whereas the `find` command traverses all directories regardless of whether they have changed.

Comment: How it's possible to check such a thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620684/directory-last-modified-date